# Spring Websocket - React Typescript - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring, typescript, spring-boot, spring-websocket, react-typescript

It is my first time using WebSocket with Spring and React Typescript.

I have configured my Spring application:

*Config file:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketMessageConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

}
```

*Security config file*

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

*Controller:*

```
@Controller
public class GrettingWSController {

    @MessageMapping("/api/ws")
    @SendTo("/topic")
    public String handle(final String greeting) {
        return "[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ": " + greeting;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to connect via frontend client (React Typescript):

```
let sockJS = this.socketFactory();
sockJS.onopen = function () {
           console.log('Client connection opened');
       };

sockJS.onerror = function (event: any) {
           console.log('Client error: ' + event);
       };

sockJS.onclose = function (event: any) {
           console.log('Client connection closed: ' + event.code);
       };

[...]

private socketFactory() {
        return new SockJS('https://localhost:8443/api/ws');
    }
```

But I get this error in Spring console:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:177)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:133)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 com.caixabank.koa.common.authentication.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Spring 4.3.14 and React 16.8.6.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Finally I added

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/ws/*").permitAll();
```

in the Spring-Security configuration and I can already connect correctly.